# JAX-WS Web Services Without Java EE Containers

Tags: java, jax-ws, endpoint

I can easily publish web services using javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.
    endpoint.publish(getURL());
I would like to know why I have to use real IP to publisg the webservice to remote. In otherwords.

> when I use the URL
>           httpp://localhost:1970/XXXService

XXService could not be connected from remote machines.

> But when 
>           httpp://47.168.96.47:1970/XXXService

is used it could be connected from any machine remotely or locally.

Comment: I have intentionally added extra "p" character to http. http://47.168.96.47:1970/XXXService

Comment: If you only bind to the localhost interface, the server will not accept remote connections.

Comment: you mean  modifying /etc/hosts file by adding the line > localhost 47.168.96.31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution over again stackoverflow. Here is the question/answer 
[link] [Publishing a WS with Jax-WS Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680600/publishing-a-ws-with-jax-ws-endpoint)

I have neither use localhost nor real ip. Instead Ihave used 0.0.0.0. It works now, service could be published externally.