# Unable to access Java SOAP service when deployed using Docker

Tags: java, docker, soap, java-web-start

I have this simple Java SOAP service which works fine in the local machine.

```java
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

@WebService
public class EchoService {
    @WebMethod
    public String echo(@WebParam(name = "message") String message) {
        return message;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/echoservice", new EchoService());
        System.out.println("Service published at http://localhost:8080/echoservice");
    }
}
```

When I start this locally, I can reach the service via http://localhost:8080/echoservice

Then I tried to use docker and deploy a containerised version. This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-11 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline

COPY src ./src
RUN mvn package

FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/target/*.jar ./app.jar
COPY --from=build /app/target/libs ./libs
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

These are my docker commands.

```bash
docker build -t java-soap:1.0 . 

docker run -p 8080:8080 java-soap:1.0
```

After starting the container, I can see the server is running but it is no longer reachable via http://localhost:8080/echoservice.

What should be the issue here?
Is this related to Docker network interfaces?
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, when you ssh to running container can you access application inside?

Comment: Processes listening only on `localhost` aren't usually accessible from outside their own containers ([Docker app server ip address 127.0.0.1 difference of 0.0.0.0 ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179831/docker-app-server-ip-address-127-0-0-1-difference-of-0-0-0-0-ip)).  Can you change the `Endpoint.publish()` URL to be 0.0.0.0 instead ([Publishing a WS with Jax-WS Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680600/publishing-a-ws-with-jax-ws-endpoint))?

Comment: @DavidMaze worked when I used `0.0.0.0`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked fine when I changed `localhost` to `0.0.0.0`.

Corrected code,

```java
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

@WebService
public class EchoService {
    @WebMethod
    public String echo(@WebParam(name = "message") String message) {
        return message;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:8080/echoservice", new EchoService());
        System.out.println("Service published at http://localhost:8080/echoservice");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to use the following host:

```
host.docker.internal
```

instead of

```
localhost
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/10620689

Comment: Please flag the question as a duplicate, if you think this is the problem.

Comment: Sorry, this did not work for me.